# What tense is "I see that ..."

Tags: tenses, present-tense, present-progressive

For example, in "I see that you have a new car." the "I see" seems to imply something like "I am seeing now" or "I noticed", rather than the usual present simple tense connotation of a habit or something that's true in the past, present and future.

What tense are such sentences considered to be in? I briefly thought imperative but that implies something that will be true in the future but isn't true now. Is there something like a "declarative" tense?

Comment: *I see* is the present tense; *I saw* is the past tense. There are no others.

Comment: Ignore the apparent tense of the term (for understanding, that is, not syntax & sentence construction).  It means "I noticed".  The implication is that this noticing occurred "recently", probably since your last encounter with the person to whom you are speaking.  Eg, you might say "I see that they tore down that old theater," even though you noticed this Friday night and you are speaking Monday morning.

Comment: It is simple present.  Simple present is used to talk about facts.  It is a fact that he sees that the person has a new car.  Are we going to start saying "birds are flying." because "birds fly" is too simple and doesn't sound sexy enough?  Do we say for a blind person "he isn't seeing."  No, we say "He can't see."

Comment: @michael_timofeev The point here is that in “birds fly”, the simple present carries a connotation of permanence and/or habit: that birds fly is a universal truth, as true yesterday as tomorrow. That’s how the simple present is most commonly used in English (except in a smallish group of verbs). But there is no such connotation in “I see that…”. If someone is currently looking at a painting, that is also a fact, but we don’t say, “I look at a painting”—we say, “I am looking at a painting”.

Comment: Yes, but you either see the fact or you don't.  It's not an active thing like looking.  Facts are yes or no things.  So for me, "see" cannot be used as a present continuous.  You wouldn't say "I'm seeing you have a new car."...would you?  Am I missing the point here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is present tense. If you noticed at sometime in the past you would say *When I arrived at his house I saw that he had a new car*.

The only thing is that *see* when used in this sense is something that has relevance to a moment (in the recent past) which has now gone - the moment when you 'saw'. But because it is relevant to the present time (his having a new car, as opposed to a past time when he had an old car) one is extending the notion of the present to include something that has recently happened.

It is a bit like saying: *I am currently playing tennis twice a week*. The playing twice-weekly probably started a few weeks ago, but because it differentiates what is happening now, as opposed to what may have happened in the past (when you only played once a week) you treat the current position as present.

Does that help?

Comment: But what about the (semantically implied?) continuous aspect of _see_? You wouldn't say "I'm seeing you have a new car". With static verbs like _know_, you have a similar phenomenon, but can _see_ be seen as a static verb?

Comment: @oerkelens You might if you were an Indian!

Comment: @oerkelens I am split two ways on this. On the one hand I am thinking that *see* in this context is static, like *know*. On the other hand I can think of it used in a continuous sense, very much like the one we are discussing e.g *I am seeing a lot of changes in Bill's life since he met Mary*. Same things apply with *hear*. *I hear you have a new car*.

Comment: You don't use "I'm seeing" with "since."  "Since" is almost always used with present perfect (continuous in this case.). "I've been seeing a lot of changes in Bill's life since he met Mary."  The present perfect connects the past ("since he left Mary") with the present "I've been seeing."  In any case, it's all bad writing--better to use "notice."

Comment: You also can't say "I'm now playing tennis twice a week."  It should be "I've been playing tennis twice a week," or "currently, I play tennis twice a week."

Comment: @michael_timofeev I certainly have to disagree with you about your second point. I see nothing at all wrong with *I am currently playing tennis twice a week*. It sounds perfectly idiomatic to me. I will give some more thought to your earlier point about *since*.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Wouldn't you agree that one could say *I am seeing/noticing/finding a lot of changes in Bill*?

Comment: One can say "I am currently..." But once you change it to "now" and add "twice a week" it doesn't work.  One can say "Now he's playing tennis."  Words like now, lately, since, currently, etc, are all linked to specific tenses and time logic.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Ah, so the argument is about linking *now* with *twice a week* . Ok then, forget my earlier point and I will change my answer to read *I am currently playing tennis twice a week* - it doesn't alter my argument.

Comment: As far as I know, "see" isn't used in the present continuous like that.  Same with "notice" and "find."  For example "what are you doing?"  "I'm looking into this telescope." Not "I'm seeing into this telescope."  See is either can or can't.  Look is seeing but with intention.  Anything with the eyes that involve intention can be used with "ing". Gawking, peering, rubber-necking, gazing, glowering, etc.  "Hear" is the same.  We say listen.

Comment: @michael_timofeev So are you saying that the word *seeing* doesn't exist? Or if it does exist, how would you use it? How about *I am seeing Bert on Friday*? *I am looking into the telescope now and I think I am seeing the planet Pluto*? *He is seeing a chiropractor about the problem*. There are all sorts of ways one can use *seeing*.

Comment: I agree there are all sorts of ways to use "seeing" but they are figurative uses.  "I'm seeing Debbie," or "I'll see to it that he does his work." (to change the tense)  or "I see what you mean."  We could probably go around in circles for hours about this.  I'm just looking at the examples given and talking about those.  BTW, the telescope and Pluto sentence...should be "I'm looking into the telescope, and I think I see Pluto."  Looking talks about what your eyes are doing and see talks about the fact...I know, it has "think" in front of it, so it's no longer a "fact."

Comment: @michael_timofeev _See_ can certainly be used in the present continuous, even without much special-case pleading. It is just that the meaning of ‘see’ (to perceive with the eyes _without intention_) is not something that generally needs to be expressed in an ongoing manner. There’s nothing wrong with “I’m not seeing the problem here” (right this instance, I am not able to see the problem, but if you explain it to me, I hope I will be), for example. Also, “I’m now playing tennis twice a week” is perfectly fine and does **not** mean the same as either of your suggested corrections.

Comment: (Though it does mean the same as “I now play tennis twice a week”.)

Comment: Ok, so the word "now" seems to have two different interpretations here: one, is "at the moment" and the other is "currently, in my life."  Ok, I concede that point.

Comment: So the difference between "I'm now playing tennis twice a week," and "I've been playing tennis twice a week" is that in the first, it is a recent switch or change and in the second, the action existed much longer in time..."I've been playing tennis twice a week since 1995."

Answer (score -1):

Present tense because seeing the car and telling at the same time.